# Helper method for java sequential search

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I need to use a helper method in a recursive sequential search for an arraylist.

Here is my helper method:

```
private int seqSearchRecHelper(int sku, int index) {
    if (index < inventory.size()) {
        if (sku == inventory.get(index).getSku()) {
            return index;
        }
        return seqSearchRecHelper(sku, index + 1);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I am just not sure how to use the helper method to write a recursive sequential search method.

All I have so far is the method name and parameter:

```
public InventoryItem seqSearchRec(int sku) {        
}
```

Comment: Why use recursion when a simple for loop would do the job?

Comment: It is for a school assignment, we are learning about recursion.

Comment: Well, this is a bad example for using recursion then.... But as a hint think of what would be the first index to search for.

Comment: Agreed, it's O(n) for memory.

Comment: Well sequential search would just search for the first index, correct? Then move on to the next one until it finds the correct one.

Comment: how your InventoryItem looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public InventoryItem seqSearchRec(int sku) {
    int i = seqSearchRecHelper(sku, 0);
    //returns null if the item is not found.
    if (i == -1) return null;
    return inventory.get(i);
}
```

It calls `seqSearchRecHelper` for 0 first because 0 is the first index. The helper method will then call itself until it finds the item or reaches the end, and the index will be passed up the call chain.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public InventoryItem seqSearchRec(int sku) {   

 int index = seqSearchRecHelper(sku,0);// send  the key to be searched(sku)
  //and the start  index(lets begin with index 0)
 if(index == -1){
    // sku not found
 }else{
     // sku found at possition index 
 }
 //   return InventoryItem object
}
```